# New column from previous columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with some columns:

```
>>data.columns.values
array(['Sheet', 'Row', 'Column', 'Cell', 'V0', 'Thx', 'dV', 'Vd'], dtype=object)
```

Each row contains a different value for the Sheet, Row, etc etc.

From the info of Sheet, Row, etc I will create a PDF file title like this:

`title = Sheet%s_Row%s_Column%s_Cell%s.pdf`

So instead of iterating over each row of the DataFrame and create a single title each time, I wanted to directly create another column of strings called `title` and store the different titles like this:

```
data['title'] = "Sheet%s_Row%s_Column%s_Cell%s" % (data['Sheet'], data['Row'], data['Column'], data['Cell'])
```

But this is not working, seems like it is appending each Serie inside each `%s`

How can I create this `title` column from the info on each row without having to iterate over the entire DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be using `DataFrame.apply()` with `axis=1`. Example -

```
data['title'] = data.apply(lambda row: "Sheet{}_Row{}_Column{}_Cell{}".format(row['Sheet'], row['Row'], row['Column'], row['Cell']) , axis=1)
```

---

Demo -

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B'],['C','D'],['E','F']] , columns=['Sheet','row'])

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
  Sheet row
0     A   B
1     C   D
2     E   F

In [54]: df['title'] = df.apply(lambda row: "Sheet{}_row{}".format(row['Sheet'],row['row']) , axis=1)

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
  Sheet row        title
0     A   B  SheetA_rowB
1     C   D  SheetC_rowD
2     E   F  SheetE_rowF
```

Comment: Thanks Anand, however, in my for-loop solution I have also used this `row['Sheet']`, etc so that makes me ask: Is this lambda funcion iterating over the entire DataFrame as well?. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is iterating over the entire DataFrame. Just that the iteration is internal to pandas.

Comment: ok so I assume that it might be faster than my solution `for index, row in data.iterrows() .......`

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with the for loop. To create a completely new column as you want, I do not think there is any vectorised method (though i can be wrong) .

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, where you specify which columns you operate on in advance:

```
var = ['Sheet','row']

df['title'] = reduce(lambda x,y: x+'_'+y, [v + df[v] for v in var])

Out[284]:
  Sheet row        title
0     A   B  SheetA_rowB
1     C   D  SheetC_rowD
2     E   F  SheetE_rowF
```